# Establish SSH connection from Jenkins container to SSH server container, I can establish with password login but can't establish with private key

Tags: docker, jenkins, ssh, centos, dockerfile

**The Story:**

I am following a Udemy course for learning Jenkins with docker. The lab is that I setup a *SSH server container* & a *Jenkins container*, put them in the same docker network. Then, I go into the jenkins container to establish ssh connection to the SSH server container.

**The issue:**

I can establish SSH connection from jenkins container to the SSH server container with password login, however, it fails to establish the `SSH -i` with the key pair I generated.

**The overview of my directory and files:**

Under my working space of my local machine, I have:

- a `docker-compose.yml` (details see below)
- a directory named `centos/`,
- Inside `centos/` I have a `Dockerfile` for building the SSH server image.

**The steps I tried and their results:**

**Step 1,** I firstly created the `docker-compose.yml` for the two containers

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - $PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home
    networks:
      - net
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote_host
    image: remote-host
    build: 
      context: centos7
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

As you can see above, the `remote_host` service refers to the SSH server image which is built from a `Dockerfile` under `centos/` directory.

**Step 2,** so here is my `Dockerfile` under `centos/` :

```
FROM centos

RUN yum -y install openssh-server

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo remote_user:1234 | chpasswd && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh/ && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized_keys

RUN ssh-keygen -A
RUN rm -rf /run/nologin
CMD /usr/sbin/sshd -D
```

**Step 3.** As you can see in above Dockerfile, I `COPY` a public key `remote-key.pub` from my local host to the container and named it `authorized_keys`. I generated the key pair under the `centos/` folder of my local host by command:

`ssh-keygen -t rsa -m PEM -f remote-key`

**Step 4.** After all above are done. I run command `docker-compose build` to build images.

**Step 5.** Finally I run `docker-compose up` to bring up containers.

Both jenkins & remote_host(the ssh server) containers are up and running successfully.

**Step 6.** Then I go inside the jenkins container by `docker exec -it jenkins bash`, in the bash terminal of the container, I do ssh connection:

```
jenkins@7551f2fa441d:/$ ssh remote_user@remote_host
remote_user@remote_host's password:
```

After input the passowrd 1234 (Defined in the `Dockerfile`), I successfully established the SSH connection from jenkins container to the SSH server container. But I would like to establish the connection via key pairs instead of password login.

**Step 7,** since the SSH server container has the public key copied, so, I copied the private key from my local host to the jenkins container by command:

```
docker cp remote-key jenkins:/tmp/
```

So, now the jenkins container's /tmp/ directory contains the private key.

**Step 8,** Now I try to use the private key to establish the SSH connection to the ssh server container. I go inside the jenkins by `docker exec -it jenkins bash`, then, I run command:

```
jenkins@7551f2fa441d:/$ ssh -i /tmp/remote-key remote_user@remote_host
Load key "/tmp/remote-key": Permission denied
remote_user@remote_host's password:
```

As you can see above, inside jenkins container, the bash prompt tells me the `key "/tmp/remote-key": Permission denied.` Right after that it asks me to input password, then I input password 1234, and the SSH connection is established.

So, why I can't use the private key to establish the SSH connection from the jenkins container to the ssh server container but only login with password works?

**==== Update =====**

Inspired by the comment from @agentsmith under his answer, I checked the ownership of the `/tmp/remote-key` inside my jenkins container:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins   jenkins       4096 Sep 20 13:01 hsperfdata_jenkins
drwxr-xr-x 2 root      root          4096 Feb  2  2020 hsperfdata_root
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins   jenkins       4096 Sep 20 13:01 jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-war-_-any-190970179478026794.dir
drwxr-xr-x 2 jenkins   jenkins       4096 Sep 18 20:55 jetty-0_0_0_0-8080-war-_-any-878046537266404011.dir
-rw------- 1 245867976 1349604816    1679 Sep 18 20:53 remote-key
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins   jenkins    3167976 Sep 18 20:55 winstone3001500689590881345.jar
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins   jenkins    3167976 Sep 20 13:01 winstone8218655308653013358.jar
```

As you can see above, all other files have user and group ownership of `jenkins` (one file with `root`) except the **remote-key** file. So I tried to change the ownership by:

```
jenkins@7551f2fa441d:/$ chown jenkins:jenkins /tmp/remote-key 
chown: changing ownership of '/tmp/remote-key': Operation not permitted
```

However the `chown` command tells me operation not permitted. :( What should I do now?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> -rw------- 1 245867976 1349604816    1679 Sep 18 20:53 remote-key
> ```

> ```
> jenkins@7551f2fa441d:/$ chown jenkins:jenkins /tmp/remote-key
> chown: changing ownership of '/tmp/remote-key': Operation not permitted
> ```
>
> However the chown command tells me operation not permitted. :( What should I do now?

Looks like permission on your SSH key are indeed not set properly. You cannot change the file permission as it's owned by `245867976` but your bash session is ran by `jenkins` user.

You should change the file ownership key using `root`:

```
docker exec -it -u root jenkins bash
$ chown jenkins:jenkins /tmp/remote-key 
$ exit
```

`-u` flag will run `bash` in `jenkins` container as `root` user, with which you should be able to change your file permission. Then try again:

```
docker exec -it jenkins bash
$ ssh -i /tmp/remote-key remote_user@remote_host
```

---

Note: you can also directly run `ssh` with `root` without needing to change permissions

```
docker exec -it -u root jenkins bash
$ ssh -i /tmp/remote-key remote_user@remote_host
```

Comment: I didn't know the `-u` option. Thanks! It solved my problem!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you basically want to run commands in other docker container.

That's totally possible. Actually, I've already written an **[answer on how to establish a ssh-connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63694859/8182504)** between two independent docker containers within the same docker network.

---

This solution I provided involves

- Static IPs in a docker network (you can also use the hostnames, but I personally prefer static IPs)
- A volume for sharing the the *public ssh-key*

---

**A note on storing sensitive files in docker:** It is advisable not to place keys, certificates whatsoever into the container's file system at all. This can be easily achieved by using docker volumes; and you would simply mount a volume holding keys/containers into the Docker container when launching it.

Comment: But could you please explain why my approach doesn't work? I understand it is not the best practice because it is a lab in a beginner course the instructor also said in future lectures he will teach a better way but current approach works in his video. My main purpose is not looking for a best practice but figure out why my approach using private key for ssh connection doesn't work from one container to another.

Comment: To troubleshoot try the following: Try changing the access of the ssh folder, and the files. `docker cp` copies the files using user root. Director should be *700*, pub key *644* and private *600*. Also add the verbose option to see why your key gets denied (`ssh -v`). please add this output to your question.

Comment: thank you, I updated my question post now, could you please take a look. I tried to change the ownership of the private key inside the jenkins container but failed.