# Should you put PHP + Cron in the same docker container?

Tags: php, docker, cron

I am fairly new to docker and I am still trying to figure out what the best practices and conventions are.

One thing I see over and over again is: **"each container should be responsible for just a single process"**.

I am coming from the average LAMP stack. So one apache server is serving multiple websites running on php, and they all have some cronjobs running (combined in a single cron-file).

So, the docker way...
A single container for mysql.
A single container for php+apache (can access the mysql container via the 'docker-network'.

But now the cronjobs. I see people saying: you should make a seperate container for that. But, to my knowning, there is no way the cron-container would be able to access the php-command from the php+apache container.

**What is the convention here? I feel like I should put the cron in the php+apache container, and just run it as an additional process in that container. Is that correct?**

Next to this: should every website have its own docker php+apache+cron container? Or is it 'allowed' to bundle them together?

Any advice? Thanks!

Comment: You should separate it. If the PHP container dies, all cronjobs are dead.

Comment: But *why* should it be able to access the php-command from the php+apache container? Why can't it access its own php?

Comment: @MarkusZeller The cronjobs will execute some php scripts. So it kind of makes sense if the php container dies the cronjobs can't be executed.

Comment: @YourCommonSense In that case I would have cron+php container next to my php+apache container? What benefit does this have then over having a php+apache+cron container?

Comment: Then ask yourself why did you move mysql container away first. It uses the same Debian/Ubuntu system as PHP-Apache container does. Why cannot mysql use the same system then? How having same piece of software in two containers can justify anything?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Haha that is a very good question. I am trying to figure out what the conventions and best practices are, but coming from a 'simple' LAMP setup, it's still hard sometimes to rewire my brain to what 'the docker way' is.

Comment: When you have apache+php, and a cron container, you could even trigger a php job via http call.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59035543/how-to-execute-command-from-one-docker-container-to-another

Comment: Consider installing cron in the container _image_ and running a second container with that same image, but invoking crond as the command instead.

Answer (score 0):

There is no right or wrong answer here, it really depends on your specific needs and preferences. If you want to keep your containers small and focused on a single task, then you would want to create a separate container for your cronjobs. However, if you don't mind having a larger container that handles multiple tasks, then you can definitely put your cronjobs in the same container as your PHP + Apache server.